# oracle adding, then avg with null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sql like:

```
select avg(decode(type, 'A', value, null) + decode(type, 'B', value, null)) from table;
```

The problem with this is some of these types can be null, so the addition part will result in null because adding anything to null makes it null. So you might think I could change the decode from null to 0, but that seems to make the avg() count it as part of it's averaging, but it shouldn't/I don't want it counted as part of the average.

Ideally the addition would just ignore the nulls and just not try to add them to the rest of the values.

So let's say my numbers are:

```
5 + 6 + 5
3 + 2 + 1
4 + null + 2
```

They total 28 and I'd want to divide by 8 (ignore the null), but if I change the null to 0 in the decode, the avg will then divide by 9 which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your code should always return `null`, since if the first `decode` returns `value`, then the second `decode` must always return `null`. I'm going to assume that you made an error in genericizing your code and that what you really meant was this:

```
avg(decode(type1, 'A', value1, null) + decode(type2, 'B', value2, null))
```

(Or, instead of `type1`, it could be `a.type`. The point is that the fields in the two decodes are meant to be separate fields)

---

In this case, I think the easisest thing to do is check for nulls first:

```
avg(case when type1 is null and type2 is null then null
    else case type1 when 'A' then value1 else 0 end
       + case type2 when 'B' then value2 else 0 end
    end)
```

(I replaced `decode` with `case` because I find it easier to read, but, in this case `decode` would work just as well.)

Comment: I think the same about OP question. +1 for CASE since DECODE is Oracle specific.

Comment: What I have in my original post is more in line with the table structure than what you are saying. Date/Type/Value. I'm decoding each different type value to pivot the table, but I need to add 4 different types together then avg them.

Comment: I'm reworking a query done by someone else. To pivot they were self joining the table for every different type, which made the query very very slow. I have all the other fields fine because they are simple avg(decode(..)), but this 1 field is avg the addition of different types.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to calculate the average yourself:

```
select 
    -- The sum of all values with type 'A' or 'B'
    sum(decode(type, 'A', value, 'B', value, 0)) /
    -- ... divided by the "count" of all values with type 'A' or 'B'
    sum(decode(type, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 0))
from table;
```

A [SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10260)

But the way `AVG()` works, it would probably be sufficient, if you just removed the addition and put everything in a single `DECODE()`

```
select avg(decode(type, 'A', value, 'B', value, null)) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is overcomplicated to do a sum here. Juste output the values with a CASE, and you are done.

```
SELECT AVG(
    CASE WHEN type = 'A' OR type = 'B' 
    THEN value
    ELSE null
    END
) 
FROM table
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the same values as the original query I'm reworking. The original would self join itself for each different type, then they would avg(a.value + b.value + c.value), but the self joining is killing performance. Basically all they were trying to do was pivot the table on type, which is why I'm using the decode for all the other columns and it works fine, but this addition before avg() is giving me problems.

Comment: Edit your post with your full query, because it's missing a lot of information.

Comment: It's not really. The only thing I'm missing is a date column and a name column. The table is date/name/type/value, and I'm pivoting on type and averaging the values, but I need to sum before pivoting on them. Let's say the types are foods and the values are daily prices. Then say I want to add all the citrus types and then avg them. That's basically the idea.

Comment: @user441521: I would strongly suggest posting both the original query with the self joins and your revised query. I'm not convinced that it's possible for you to get the same results as the original query with the changes you've made.

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is a bit complicated:

```
select avg((case when type = 'A' then value else 0 end) + (case when type = 'B' then value else 0 end))
from table
where type in ('A', 'B')
```

The `where` clause guarantees that you have at least one "A" or "B".  The problem is arising when you have no examples of "A" or "B".